# Output capacitance of H-Bridge IC (DRV8432DKD) for snubber design

Tags: h-bridge, emc, snubber

all. I have implemented a hydraulic pump driver circuit using a [DRV8432DKD](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/drv8412.pdf) (36-HSSOP package).  I provided pads for an RC snubber on my PCB, but I am having some trouble coming up with the values for the snubber's parts because I cannot find any information in the datasheet for the output capacitance of the IC's output FETs.  Most (if not all) discrete FETs list a dynamic output capacitance (Coss) in their datasheet, and then a good starting value of the snubber capacitor is (Coss + mounting capacitance) * 2.

My initial thought is to survey a few of discrete FETs in similar packages with similar current ratings and use their values of Coss.  Any guidance in this area would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What exactly are you snubbing? It's very unusual that the snubber values depend on the characteristics of the switching elements; normally, the inductance and current (stored energy) of the load are the key parameters.

Answer (score 1):

You can measure it in circuit by measuring the ringing frequency across the motor with and without a **known value added capacitor**.

Since \$f_{ring} = \frac{1}{2\pi \sqrt {L C}} \$, if you measure the ringing with and with out \$C_{add}\$  as fring1 and fring0 respectively, then

C = \$\frac {C_{add}}{x^2 -1}\$ where x = \$ \frac {f_{ring0}}{f_{ring1}}\$

This method is described in [this](http://www.nxp.com/documents/application_note/AN11160.pdf) NXP application note **AN11160 Designing RC Snubbers**.